# youtube has changed the appearance after dec 2012 and how to revert to the old look

Tags: youtube, user-friendly

Youtube has changed the appearance.

Now it looks like a junk blog created by a dummy designer.

Every thing is looking like black ink blotted on a white paper.

How do we revert it back to its classy distinguishable interface.

Comment: How does this relate to Webmasters? Perhaps more suited to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

As of now you can't. You can send them feedback on the lower right hand section of the screen (a feedback button is present). Even I didn't like the YouTube layout that much.